# Is there a way to hyperlink a bunch of files through a specific folder in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below of hyperlinking a bunch of files under a file folder. What this code does is that it makes me pick the folder I want to hyperlink. How can I give it specific folder to hyperlink for me already without asking me the filepath?

```
Sub Example1()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xFSO As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Set xFiDialog = Nothing
    If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        i = i + 1
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i + 12, 1), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `xPath = "YourFoulderPath`?

Comment: E.g. `xPath = "D:\Temp"`

Comment: What BigBen and RaymondWu are saying -- Comment out or remove code lines after `Dim i As Integer` and before `Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`  .... don't remove those two lines and mention between those two lines your folder path as `xPath = "D:\FolderA\FolderB"`